# Lightbox for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox

Does anyone know of a good lightbox plugin for rails? I found redbox but it seems to be out of development.

Thanks!

-Elliot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just use the regular Lightbox 2. Include all the appropriate javascript and stylesheets then :rel => "lightbox" on your links.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you add javascripts and stylesheets and the usage in the .html.erb (view) file??

Answer (score 4):

Here is example how to easily use lightbox in rails (v4 in my case):
1. Download from site: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
2. Copy lightbox.js to app/assets/javascripts
3. Copy lightbox.css to app/assets/stylesheets
4. Rename lightbox.css to lightbox.css.scss.erb
5. Copy four img's to app/assets/images
6. Edit lightbox.css.scss.erb:
    - All image paths replace with:

```
<%=image_path "close.png"%>
```

with proper image name.
Add a data-lightbox attribute to any image link to activate Lightbox. For the value of the attribute, use a unique name for each image. For example:

```
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```

Thats all.

Comment: Rather than using erb-processing for the css file and thus `<%= image_path ... %>`, instead save it only as `lightbox.css.scss` and use `image-url("close.png")` in the file in place of `url(...)`. No need for erb here!

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with the jQuery version?

Jquery on Rails

http://railstips.org/2008/11/20/jquery-on-rails-why-bother

Answer (score 0):

You can try [lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/), don't know if there is any rails plugin to use it, but writing some helper functions shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://github.com/Lipsiasoft/lightbox

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [rlightbox](http://ryrych.github.com/rlightbox2/). It is a jquery UI plugin. It can be used for photos and videos and the documentation is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own Rails wrapper to use Lightbox inside your existing Rails application.

Github: https://github.com/vernondegoede/lightbox-rails

Comment: How can I use it? Just add the Gemfile? That's it?