# Render 2 views at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, web

I'm kinda new to rails so forgive if this is a stupid question.

The scenario is:

I got my events controller with a index view that shows all events on the page. Now, what i want to achieve is: User clicks on one of the events, lightbox comes up showing all info about about that one event, with all the other events still behind the dark background of the lightbox. User closes the light box and process repeats. Pinterest is a good example of what i'm trying to do.

At the moment, i got these 2 views working properly. User clicks on the event and is taken to the show action.

So i'm wondering if what i'm trying to do is RESTfully achievable(without too much hacking around) in rails(3.2.8) and if so, would appreciate some insight as to where i should start from.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you want to achieve, it has nothing to do with actually rendering 2 views at the same time. What you're describing is simply making an ajax call with lightbox that opens up an URL that renders another view in the shown DIV or IFRAME (whatever lightbox uses)...

Depending on which version of Rails you use the implementation of this looks a bit different. But actually what you have to do is simply include LightBox2 in your Rails app, by simply adding the appropriate JS and CSS files and then supply the necessary class at your `link_to` calls...

Hope it's clear what I mean.

**UPDATE**
See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280793/lightbox-for-rails) for further info.

Comment: Oh great! i assumed that would be the case. I just wanted confirmation from someone that knows better in case there was a better(rails native?) solution if you know what i mean. Thanks a lot :)